# undisplayed error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, compiler-errors

Yesterday I bumped in some 'weird' issue from my point of view .
 
I was writing some code in a Laravel project , and when I was testing it , the site cracked . 
No error was displayed ,just the page thrown when a server is not working (Server not found , Connection reset , check your connection cable etc) . 
The only way I got the error was when I looked in Apache error log , and it was an PHP error 
`(Fatal error : try to use null!==object)` in the code I've wrote  . 
My question is : How could that be possible ? The website couldn't reach the bootstrap page index.php even though the error was in a different controller .

This is the line of code :

```
isset($rowSeats->first()->seatOptions()->option('held')->first())
```

Comment: Can you post the code on which it is failing.(the end-point your testing)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do after the isset . any call to `first()` will return an object. You can always check if any record is returned with the following code

```
if($rowSeats->first()->->seatOptions()->option('held')->first())
```